# Restricting IP address access in lighttp with a Django project with fastcgi

Tags: django, fastcgi, lighttpd

I have a Django project that runs with lighttp with fastcgi as following. I am trying to block certain IP addresses from accessing my django's admin panel as an extra security measure. (I realize it's not a complete solution)

For some reason what I'm doing doesn't work.

My config:

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "(^|\.)project\.whateverdomain\.com$" {
    fastcgi.server = (
        "/django.fcgi" => (
            "main" => (
                "socket" => env.HOME + "/project/project.sock",
                "check-local" => "disable",
            )
        ),
    )
    alias.url = (
        "/media" => env.HOME + "/project/project/media",
        "/static" => env.HOME + "/project/project/static",
    )

    $HTTP["url"] =~ "/static" {
        expire.url = ( "" => "access plus 2 months" )
    }
    $HTTP["url"] =~ "/media" {
        expire.url = ( "" => "access plus 2 months" )
    }
    $HTTP["remoteip"] == "1.2.3.4" { # <----- this here doesn't work
            url.access-deny = ( "/admin" )
        }
    }



    url.rewrite-once = (
        "^(/media.*)$" => "$1",
        "^(/static.*)$" => "$1",
        "^/favicon\.ico$" => "/media/favicon.ico",
        "^(/.*)$" => "/django.fcgi$1",
    )
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You might get more of a response on serverfault.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a simple middleware that does this.  Blocking IP at the server level would be better performance, but creating a small middleware that checks for blacklisted IP's would be easier to use.  You could create a model and add IP's through the admin instead of editing your server config file.